# If a logging warning occurs before __main__, how is it being called?

Tags: python, buck

I'm working on a corporate python program which uses buck build. When I run part of the program, abc.py (via a .par file), then it runs the program starting with `if __name__ == "__main__"` etc.

However, I'm trying to find source of logging warnings that occur before any of the contents of the `if __name__ ...` are run. Or perhaps keywords to understand this better. What could be running before the main file?

Comment: Python code is interpreted linearly, from the top down.  So, any imports you do get executed long before any of the code in your script.

Comment: `if __name__ == "__main__"` would typically call function(s) defined or imported earlier in the script. It is also possible that there are lines of code outside of a function that run regardless of what is called within the `__main__` block which would generate the warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is thinking execution starts with `if __name__ == "__main__":`. That check is a guard that *prevents* the guarded code from executing when imported as a module, rather than run as the main script. The *unguarded* code *always* runs, regardless of how the module is loaded, so if the guard is at the bottom of the file, the rest of the file is run before it is reached.

So if you have a module:

```
# foo.py
print("foo")
```

And a script:

```
# main.py
import foo

def main():
    print("Main")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and you run `python3 main.py`, execution of `main.py` begins with `import foo`, which ends up `print`ing `foo` immediately. Then `main.py` defines the `main` function (defining functions without calling them is still executing code; if Python had skipped to the guarded code, `main` wouldn't exist), then the guard is checked, the check passes, and `main` is called. Basically every bit of top-level code (typically imports, global constants, functions, and class definitions) is executed before the guarded block is reached; normally that top-level code does nothing visible, but if an imported module tried to do some real work and logged during the process, it would take effect before you ever reached your guarded "main script" code.